# Docker volume not working with subfolders which are blobfuse mounts

Tags: docker-compose, azure-blob-storage, docker-volume, fuse, cvat

I want to link two different azure blob storages to CVAT tools as connected file share. I used blobfuse service to mount those blob storage on a Linux machine. The folder structure looks like following:

```
Blob_mount_point
      - storage_1
      - storage_2
```

where storage_1 and storage_2 are blobfuse mount. Now i want to link this parent directory as a docker volume to cvat container but this is not showing me the contents of storage_1 and storage_2 subfolders. When i create volume based on these individual storage_1 or storage_2 it works.
Below is the docker compose file i am using

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  cvat:
    environment:
      ALLOWED_HOSTS: '*'
      CVAT_SHARE_URL: 'Mounted from /mnt/share host directory'
    volumes:
      - cvat_share:/home/django/share:ro

volumes:
  cvat_share:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/user/blob_mount
      o: bind
```

I used following file as a work around for using two separate volumes for each blobfuse mounts:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
 
  cvat:
 
    environment:
 
      ALLOWED_HOSTS: '*'
 
      CVAT_SHARE_URL: 'Mounted from /mnt/share host directory'
 
    volumes:
 
      - cvat_share_blobstor_1:/home/django/share/blobstor_1:ro
 
      - cvat_share_blobstor_2:/home/django/share/blobstor_2:ro
 

 
volumes:
 
  cvat_share_blobstor_1:
 
    driver_opts:
 
      type: none
 
      device: /home/user/blob_mount/blobstor_1
 
      o: bind
 
  cvat_share_blobstor_2:
 
    driver_opts:
 
      type: none
 
      device: /home/user/blob_mount/blobstor_2
 
      o: bind
```

Comment: did you manged to solve this?

Comment: @SatyamPandey unfortunately not. I went with the second approach and used two separate volumes for each blobfuse mount. I have updated my problem with solution i used. I hope it helps.

Comment: `transport endpoint is not connected` I get this error. As soon as i run `docker-compose up` blobfuse volume is unmounted and I get the error.Any help?